# Passing an object with a function from one component to another (app.js to navbar.js)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, function, object, parameter-passing

I'm trying to figure out how to pass an object with a function in it, then assign it to a

tag.

The code:

App.js:

```
function App() {

  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
  }

  const notLoggedInArray =[
    {name:"Login", href: "./Login"}, 
    {name:"Register", href: "./Register"},
    {name:"Bunnies", href: "./Bunnies"}];

  const LoggedInArray = [
    {name:"Logout", href: "./", onClick: logout}, 
    {name:"Bunnies", href: "./Bunnies"}];

  return (    
    
    <div>
    <RemoveScrollBar />  
      <NavBar items = {localStorage.getItem('token')
          ? LoggedInArray
          : notLoggedInArray}/>
      <Route path="/"> 
        <Home />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Login"> 
        <Login />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Register"> 
        <Register />
      </Route>
      <Route path="/Bunnies"> 
        <BunnyLogo name = 'Adiel' bodyColor = "#FFFF00" earsColor = '#00F000' faceColor = '#FF0000'/>
      </Route> 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Navbar.js:

```
const NavBar = (props) => {
        //Get the item list based on whether the user logged in or not (logic handled on app.js) then populate itemList with Link refs
    const itemList = props.items.map((item, index) => {
        return <li key ={index}><Link  href={item.href} onClick = {item.onClick} className="nav-item">{item.name}</Link></li>
    })
    return (
        <nav className="navbarItems">
            <h1><a className="navbarLogo" href = "./">Bunnify</a></h1>
            <div className="menuIcon">
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul className = "navbarMenu">
                    {itemList}
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}

export default NavBar;
```

After an hour and a half of logging and testing, I tried doing multiple changes that includes:

```
onClick = () => logout, onClick = () => logout(), onClick = () => {actual function}
```

But nothing worked!

I figured that there's something wrong when assiging the onClick property to the logout function, but I just cant pinpoint what.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a code sandbox, it seems your logic is working for the most part when I apply it to a simplified version of your application.

https://codesandbox.io/s/purple-shadow-2mz0i?file=/src/NavBar.js

the code is as follows:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import NavBar from "./NavBar";

function App() {
  const login = () => {
    localStorage.setItem("token", 123456);
  };

  const logout = () => {
    localStorage.removeItem("token");
  };

  const notLoggedInArray = [
    { name: "Login", href: "./Login", onClick: login },
    { name: "Register", href: "./Register" },
    { name: "Bunnies", href: "./Bunnies" }
  ];

  const LoggedInArray = [
    { name: "Logout", href: "./", onClick: logout },
    { name: "Bunnies", href: "./Bunnies" }
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <NavBar
        items={localStorage.getItem("token") ? LoggedInArray : notLoggedInArray}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Navbar:

```
import React from "react";

const NavBar = (props) => {
  //Get the item list based on whether the user logged in or not (logic handled on app.js) then populate itemList with Link refs
  const itemList = props.items.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <li key={index}>
        <a href={item.href} onClick={item.onClick} className="nav-item">
          {item.name}
        </a>
      </li>
    );
  });
  return (
    <nav className="navbarItems">
      <h1>
        <a className="navbarLogo" href="./">
          Bunnify
        </a>
      </h1>
      <div className="menuIcon"></div>
      <div>
        <ul className="navbarMenu">{itemList}</ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

this leads me to believe maybe something to do with how you are storing the token in localStorage is incorrect.

Comment: I have figured out what the problem was!
Check out my answer.

Comment: where is said answer?

Comment: posted it right now!
The issue was never the way I passed the property, but what I did afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, the problem was that I used `this.onClick` instead of `this.onClick()`, which should have worked properly, but because I have sent two objects to the navbar, one of them not having an onClick property at all here:

```
    { name: "Logout", href: "./", onClick: logout },
    { name: "Bunnies", href: "./Bunnies" }
```

I received an error that "onClick" is not a function, which led me to assume theres something wrong with how I passed the function, but thats not true.

When navbar receives the objects, Bunnies `onClick` property is undefined (from never assigning it in the first place), which is not a function and that's what caused the whole problem.

Adding an argument to only add onClick when onClick is a function (or not undefined) fixed it.

```
        if(item.onClick !==  undefined) {
            return <li key ={index}><Link  href={item.href} onClick = {item.onClick()} className="nav-item">{item.name}</Link></li>    
        } else {
            return <li key ={index}><Link  href={item.href} className="nav-item">{item.name}</Link></li>
        }
```

I'll tweak it later to be less redundant, but that's the solution.